# How to make method to do and undo with priority? JAVA

Tags: java, stack, queue

I'm doing a project that has to do with a package delivery service.
After putting them in context, when a package is delivered, I want to undo that action, meaning that the package is returned and not delivered.
That is to say, a logical method that has those operations of doing and undoing.
I'm using priority queues and stacks.

If you could guide me, I would be really grateful.

Comment: I think you'll need to be a bit more clear. I mean, from how I'm interpreting it, you have a stack of jobs and you want a process that, when the first job in the queue is completed, will take out that job and replace it with a return job. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

No, look imagine it, I will give you a package or a shipment, and I gave it to you, but it turns out that it was not for you, but for your friend, I press an undo button and I take your package or shipment and I give it to him.